# VBA Round() function always returns zero when input is in scientific notation

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, scientific-notation

I have a strange issue with the Round() VBA function. When I try rounding any input in scientific notation it always returns zero:

? Cells(3, 34).Value

**8,77796901893289E-02**

? Round(Cells(3, 34).Value, 0)

**0**

? Round(8.777, 0)

9

Any clues how to make it work?

Comment: Well... 8e-2 = 0.08 so the result seems correct...

Comment: "8.77796901893289E-02" (American '.' sorry :P) means 0.087796901893289, which when rounded to zero decimal places _IS_ 0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8,77796901893289E-02 equals 0,0877796901893289, so it would round to zero.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you are running into is that `round` deals with "number of digits" not significant figures.

This number of digits refers to number of decimal points.  The image below shows the example from the help file.

[image]